# Linear programming with non-convex quadratic constraint

Tags: optimization, qclp, non-convex-optimization

Could anyone let me know if the following linear programming problem can be solved in polynomial time or should be NP-hard?

$\min c^Tx$

s.t. $x^TQx\geq C^2, x\in [0,1]^n,c\in \mathbb{R}_+^n,Q\in\mathbb{R}_+^{n\times n}$ is positive semi-definite matrix.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you can't.

This is a not convex problem due to the quadratic constraint. If your $Q$ matrix were negative semidefinite, then it would have been solvable in polynomial time.

Comment: thanks, AC_MOSEK. I changed the objective function since it does not make sense to consider max function here. It is known that if we remove the bounds on the variables, the problem should be solved in polynomial time (quadratic program with only one quadratic constraint is known to be in P).

Comment: Peter your problem is yet non-convex: the feasible region is not convex, just plot what it might be $x^2 + y^2\geq 1$.

Comment: AC_MOSEK: yes, I know that it is still non-convex problem. As far as I know, however, there are no NP-hard results known for this special case.

Comment: I cannot confirm that...but if you have no results for a special case, you must keep those for the general one! So in general this is NP-hard...

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that this problem can be solved in polynomial time.

It is well known that $\min_x c'x$, such that $x'Qx \geq C$ can be solved in polynomial time (since SDP relaxation is tight). Your problem has extra bound constraints $x_i$ in $[0,1]$, which may or may not change the answer. But I think it is quite possible.

Comment: Please use Mathjax to format math.